# How to know from which activity an error comes from my application in production?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application is 2 months in production and I was checking the section that shows the play console crashing and I have been able to solve some problems, but there are some in which I do not know exactly what activity they come from, mi error is `java.lang.IllegalStateException` and when I press see more:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:115)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run (SerialExecutor.java:91)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:300)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:218)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:737)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:284)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:251)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner (SQLiteDatabase.java:1386)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open (SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:967)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:955)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:448)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:391)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:352)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp (ForceStopRunnable.java:156)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:87)
```

Out of 750 users who have installed my application it happened to one 5 times, Should a bug that happened to a single user (of 750) be investigated or not?, And most importantly, how can I know exactly where the error came from?

Comment: When throwing an exception, put the user that is currently being accessed so you can track it down.  Put as much info in the exception as possible that will help you figure out which item might be causing it.

Comment: I am not an expert in catching exceptions, "put the user that is currently being accessed so you can track it down", How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When throwing an exception, put the user that is currently being accessed so you can track it down. Put as much info in the exception as possible that will help you figure out which item might be causing it.

https://stackify.com/best-practices-exceptions-java/

These are some good examples as well as good practices to follow.  In those messages that are mentioned, add the user id or something that helps you identify what's going on.  Learn to make custom exceptions and catch the most specific exceptions you can.  Don't just catch Exception, its better to be specific about the exception your catching rather than casting a wide net.

Comment: at no point traceback contains anything outside system libraries. How would one put anything into exception generated without your calls in stack?

Comment: While the exception is being thrown only by API calls that you do not own, you are using a 3rd party library.  You might want to put in some log statements whenever you are using the sqlight calls.  The system is telling you it can't open the database.  I would start by putting logging statements all around where the database is being called and look for the exception that proceeds it.